# chrome extension - usage onChanged in background.js, content_script.js and iframe

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, storage

I'm developing a chrome extension.

The scenario is as follows:

I use **background.js** that controls the notification settings of my extension.

**Content_script.js**, which captures information from the current window and **inserts an iframe** page of the same extension.

**Frame_content.js**: This is a tab that appears in the right part of the window and that when it is clicked it is displayed.

Example:

step 1
http://oi67.tinypic.com/kcm336.jpg
step 2
http://oi64.tinypic.com/28w1pp3.jpg

I am using chrome.storage.sync to communicate between bg.js , Content_script.js and Frame_content.js and display the tab depending on whether or not it is clicked.

**My problem is that when using the listener chrome.storage.onChanged.addListener, it modifies the storage of all chrome windows and open all tabs. I need it to work ONLY in the current window.**

**That is, when I click on the tab it is displayed in all the browser windows and when I do it small happens the same.**

¿Any solution?